# how can i get the sidebar height to adjust to the main content boxes?

Tags: html, css

Im very much a beginner, Ive done a search on google but couldn't get an appropriate answer. Ive made a 2 column simple website and what I want is the sidebar (class="sideright") to match the height of there adjacent main sections (respectively). Is this something I could do using solely CSS?

```css
.main {
    
    background-color: #e5e4d7;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 340px 10px 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.sideright {
    background-color: #e5e4d7;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    float: right;
    width: 300px;

}
```

```html
 <div class="sideright">
        <h2>Sumthing</h2>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
    </div>


    <div class="main">

        <h1>This is a brilliant paragraph</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula. </p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula. </p>


    </div>
    <div class="sideright">
        <h2>Anything</h2>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <h1>This is a brilliant paragraph</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula. </p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula. </p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using flexbox. However I would make a few changes to your HTML if possible...

Wrap the sidebar and the content in a row. And while you're at it, swap their position within the row.

```
<div class="row>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

Then simply add `display: flex` to `.row`.

You can then simplify your CSS further by removing some of the `margin` properties you have added.

To ensure that your sidebar width is respected, use `min-width` instead of `width`.

[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/MJGGOj)

**SNIPPET**:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.main {
  background-color: #e5e4d7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: 10px;
}

.sideright {
  background-color: #e5e4d7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="main">

    <h1>This is a brilliant paragraph</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices
      diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis
      non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula. </p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices
      diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis
      non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula. </p>


  </div>
  <div class="sideright">
    <h2>Sumthing</h2>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="main">

    <h1>This is a brilliant paragraph</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices
      diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis
      non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula. </p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices
      diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis
      non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula. </p>


  </div>
  <div class="sideright">
    <h2>Sumthing</h2>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Be sure to use vendor prefixes with flexbox for cross browser support.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the flexbox properties :

- `display:flex` CSS grid system.
- `flex-flow:row-reverse`  to set right bar on the right, reverse the flow, not page direction
- `flex : 1 0 XX` to size and set box behavior
- `calc()` eventually usefull here.

```css
.main,
.sideright {
  background-color: #e5e4d7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  flex:1 0 calc(100% - 380px);
}
.sideright {
  flex: 1 0 300px;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-flow:row-reverse;
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sideright">
        <h2>Sumthing</h2>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
    </div>


    <div class="main">

        <h1>This is a brilliant paragraph</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula. </p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula. </p>


    </div>
    <div class="sideright">
        <h2>Anything</h2>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
        <p>sum</p>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <h1>This is a brilliant paragraph</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula. </p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula. </p>
    </div>
```

---

**If you do not want to use the flex properties** ,

you may use the **table properties**, but each couple of boxes will need to be wrapped together.

- `display:table;` , `display:table-row;`, `display:table-cell;`
- `table-layout:fixed` + `width`
- `border-spacing` instead `margin`
- `direction` to set and reset ... direction

```css
.main,
.sideright {
  background-color: #e5e4d7;
  border-radius: 5px;
 /* margin: 10px; use border-spacing instead */
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  direction: ltr;/* reset flow to left to right */
  display: table-cell;
}
.sideright {
  width: 300px;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
body {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;/* make sure it won't expand */
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border-spacing: 10px;/* instead margin unavalaible for the children boxes */
  direction: rtl;/* reverse flow direction */
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="sideright">
    <h2>Sumthing</h2>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
  </div>


  <div class="main">

    <h1>This is a brilliant paragraph</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices
      diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis
      non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices
      diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis
      non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula.</p>


  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="sideright">
    <h2>Anything</h2>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
    <p>sum</p>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <h1>This is a brilliant paragraph</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices
      diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis
      non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula.</p>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas lorem nisi, congue vitae vestibulum faucibus, congue non lacus. Nulla eu ultricies leo. Sed at augue eleifend, hendrerit metus quis, pellentesque massa. Phasellus non odio ultrices
      diam vestibulum eleifend. Quisque vehicula vel diam eget lobortis. Sed ut eros arcu. Phasellus vulputate lectus risus, id bibendum neque elementum placerat. Pellentesque congue mattis libero vel rutrum. Ut vel urna vitae dolor pulvinar gravida quis
      non magna. Etiam eget urna eleifend, pretium purus ut, tempor sapien. Pellentesque pellentesque, libero at hendrerit malesuada, risus odio rutrum libero, id ultricies erat urna et ligula.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```